# Can't center a paragraph in a div

Tags: html, css

I have tried using flexbox to center a couple buttons and a `p` but I'm having some troubles.

I have this code

```css
.container {
  background: rgb(255, 126, 50, 0.15);
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  margin: 3.625rem 1.25rem 2rem 1.25rem;
  background: black;
}

.layout {
  height: calc(100vh - 4.5rem);
  background: balck;
}

.loginSection {
  width: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.loginSection p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 16px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12rem;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.btn-login {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;

  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-login img {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.btn-continue {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;

  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="loginSection">
      <button class="btn-login" href="/login">
        Log-In
      </button>

      <p>Enter your email</p>

      <button class="btn-continue" href="/home">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I can center the `p`

```
|    |      Log-In      |    |
|Enter your email   |
|    | Continue         |    |
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the problem was in the incorrect use of ```flexbox```. I refactored your code a bit, I guess that's what you were trying to achieve? [Code Snippet in Codepen](https://codepen.io/jphawk/pen/XWXNqQJ)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  background: rgb(255, 126, 50, 0.15);
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  margin: 3.625rem 1.25rem 2rem 1.25rem;
  background: black;
}

.layout {
  height: calc(100vh - 4.5rem);
  background: balck;
}

.loginSection {
  width: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.layout p {
    text-align: center;
width: 12rem;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
color: white;
margin: auto;
}

.btn-login {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;

  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-login img {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.btn-continue {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;

  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="loginSection">
      <button class="btn-login" href="/login">
        Log-In
      </button>

      <p>Enter your email</p>

      <button class="btn-continue" href="/home">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is typically used by setting flex properties on the *parent container* to affect the layout of the *children* inside of that container.

It looks like you're adding `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on the `.loginSection p` element, when flex properties should be set on the parent `.loginSection`.

If your intention is to center all the elements inside of the `.loginSection` horizontally, then you can get rid of the flex properties on the children, and add the following rules:

```
.loginSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  // ... other styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `display:flex` with `flex-direction: column` and `align-items:center` to the `.loginSection` container.

Typically when using flex, you flex the container and then the children become "flex-items" rather than flexing the items themselves.

```css
.loginSection {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
}

.loginSection p { text-align:center; }
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="loginSection">
      <button class="btn-login" href="/login">
        Log-In
      </button>

      <p>Enter your email</p>

      <button class="btn-continue" href="/home">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want them to all be stretched out use `align-items:stretch`

```css
.loginSection {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem; /* optional if you don't want it to stretch the whole width */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:stretch;
}

.loginSection p { text-align:center; }
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="loginSection">
      <button class="btn-login" href="/login">
        Log-In
      </button>

      <p>Enter your email</p>

      <button class="btn-continue" href="/home">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```